# mysql - query example request

Tags: mysql

Updated

Hello all,

MySQL here.

Let's say we have 3 tables.

**TableA**, **TableB**, **TableC**.

**TableB** *relates* with foreign keys, **TableA** and **TableC**.

I would like to: 
List some data from **TableA** and **TableC** BUT, that data should be ordered by some column of **TableB**.

Can I have an example of the above so that I can study it and try to transform to my needs?

Thanks a lot.
MEM

Comment: Thanks a lot.I do see joins. I do see inner joins. I believe I can also see left joins. On this case, is it a question of preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql allows you to order by colums that not selected, so you can join your tables 
`select ta.somefield, tc.somefield` 
`from TableA ta INNER JOIN TableC tc on tc.somefield=ta.somefield` 
`INNER JOIN TableB tb on tb.somefield=ta.somefield` 
`ORDER by tb.somefield`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TABLEA.fieldnames, TABLEC.fieldnames FROM TABLEA, TABLEB, TABLEC WHERE TABLEA.PRIMARY=TABLEB.TABLEA_PRIMARY AND TABLEC.PRIMARY=TABLEB.TABLEC_PRIMARY ORDER BY TABLEC.fieldname DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    tA.blah,
    tA.goop,
    tC.schmarr,
    tC.broigle
from
    tB
        join tA on tA.joincol1 = tB.joinCol1
        join tC on tC.joinColx = tB.joinColx
order by
    tc.schmarr
```